# Having trouble calling Classes in Python

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to teach myself how to use classes and I'm trying an example I found in a book that asks you to create two classes and then print out some information. Here is my code:

```
import math
import turtle
import urllib.request


class Shape:
    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def calc_area(self):
        pass
    def calc_perim(self):
        pass
    def get_shape_type(self):
        return "s"
    def to_string(self):
        return "%s %f %f" % (self.get_shape_type(), self.x, self.y)
    def get_draw_params(self):
        return [self.x, self.y]

class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0,rad=0):
        super().__init__(x,y)
        self.radius = rad
    def calc_area(self):
        area = math.pi * self.radius * self.radius
        return area
    def calc_perim(self):
        perim = 2 * math.pi * self.radius
        return perim
    def calc_circumference(self):
        return self.calc_perim()
    def get_shape_type(self):
        return "c"
    def to_string(self):
        return "%s %f %f %f" % (super().to_string(), self.radius, self.calc_area(),self.calc_perim())
    def get_draw_params(self):
        result = super().get_draw_params()
        result.extend([self.radius])
        return result

cir = Circle(0,0,150)
print(cir)
```

When I try to run it, it prints this:

```
<__main__.Circle object at 0x103d19ef0>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong when I'm calling the Circle class. I was hoping that after putting in the values that the init function asks for, there would be some data to print out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong.. you printed out the object representation of that class.. if you want to see more information you would need to print out something like `print cir.method`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling the `to_string()` method that you added to your classes:

```
>>> cir = Circle(0,0,150)
>>> print(cir)
<__main__.Circle object at 0x7fba2851b400>
>>> print(cir.to_string())
c 0.000000 0.000000 150.000000 70685.834706 942.477796
```

If you are wanting a customised string representation, try adding `__unicode__()` and/or `__str__()` methods to your classes:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.to_string()
```

Now you can do this:

```
>>> c = Circle(0,0,150)
>>> print(c)
c 0.000000 0.000000 150.000000 70685.834706 942.477796
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite right, this is how python prints your object,

if you want your print(object) print something else, define [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method in your class, something like this (it should return an string):

```
class Circle(Shape):
    # your stuff
    # ...
    def __str__(self):
        return "radius: " + self.radius

cir = Circle(0,0,150)
print(cir)
# radius: 150
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as my answer, although it does not reuse the existing `to_string()` method.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with what you did. Everything is working fine.

This: `<__main__.Circle object at 0x103d19ef0>`

is indicating to you have you have an object of Circle. So, if you add this:

```
print(cir.calc_area())
```

You will end up getting the area result you expect.

Furthermore, a neat bit of information that can help you is if you want to find out more information about what is inside your objects, you can do this:

```
print(dir(cir))
```

This will tell you what is housed inside your 'cir' object and you will also see that your methods you created should be there as well. Always handy to find out what is available to you even when you import other modules when you dive deeper in to Python.

Documentation on [dir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir)

Answer (score -1):

Well, that is the default representation of a `Circle` object when you print it.

Now you can call the methods of `cir`, like

```
print(cir.calc_area())
```